# Case when and coalesce is not working with openquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
select * from openquery(servername,'select vndr_num as VendorNum,t1,t2,t3,
case when trim(t1) is not null then t1
     when trim(t2) is not null then t2
     else t3
end as TAX,
coalesce(t1,t2,t3) as TID
from Mck.table_name')
```

I expect the data in column t2/t3 should be copied to TAx and TID columns when t1 is blank but in both **case when** and **coalesce** functions ,the result is same. If this is not possible with case when and coalesce please suggest any other options.

```
Vnum t1       t2        t3       Tax            TID
1                   
2                   
3               86-0378223          
4               95-2743174          
5               81-3997819          
6   532-98-0158                  532-98-0158    532-98-0158
7               82-2010249          
8               46-2037641          
9               32-0119411
```

Comment: Do you get the required result if you execute the query on the target server directly, not via openquery ?

Comment: I want the required result with openquery only, because I'm connecting to multiple servers from this server. 
I suspect there are some hidden values in column t1 due to which coalesce function not moving forward to read t2/t3 values. If its the case can we delete those hidden values with trim?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, and standard SQL and almost every DBMS for that matter, a string can be NULL or empty, and these are two different things. This is a concept that is not intuitive to us humans. If we have a supplier table with a supplier address column, we either know the address and put it there, or we don't know the address and leave it empty. But which "empty"? We must decide between NULL and '', the empty string.

You must decide, which empty to use, because they behave differently. I suppose that most often we use NULL and apply a check constraint that prevents us from writing an empty string. (If we follow this route further, we can even apply a check constraint that only allows strings that don't consist of white space, so that it's either NULL or contains at least one readable character.)

In your case an empty string column can be anything from `NULL`, `''`, `' '` to some lengthy `'       '`. If we only consider the blank character as possible white space, you only want to look at strings that have a length greater than zero when trimmed:

```
select 
vndr_num as vendornum, t1, t2, t3,
case when len(trim(t1)) > 0 then t1
     when len(trim(t2)) > 0 then t2
     else t3
end as tax
from mck.table_name;
```

(If there can be other white space, you'll have to state this in the `TRIM` function. On [stackexchange/.../trim-whitespace...](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132966/trim-whitespace-spaces-tabs-newlines) I found this: `TRIM( NCHAR(0x09) + NCHAR(0x20) + NCHAR(0x0D) + NCHAR(0x0A) FROM t1)`).

Comment: This works fine. As I'm connecting SAP HANA from SQL server with openquery,  have to use length instead of len. Thanks for the help.